# Parallel build execution in gradle

Tags: build.gradle, build-time, parallel-execution

Current scenario: 
current `build.gradle` is taking 2 hours to complete all tasks.

What i want to achieve:
i want to reduce the build time.

What i have done till now:
i have created multiple projects in below hierarchy:

```
:root project
 settings.gradle
 - rootProject.name = 'creating-multi-project'
 - include child1
 - include child2
 - include child3
 properties.gradle
 - org.gradle.parallel=true
 - org.gradle.max
:child1
 -  build.gradle
:child2
 -  build.gradle
:child3
 -  build.gradle
```

How i can confirm my tasks are running in parallel?

Tasks are running but i am not sure these are running in parallel or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Current scenario**

current build.gradle is taking 2 hours to complete all tasks.

**What i want to achieve**: i want to reduce the build time.

**What i have done till now:** i have created multiple projects in below hierarchy:

:root project
 settings.gradle
 - rootProject.name = 'creating-multi-project'
 - include child1
 - include child2
 - include child3
 properties.gradle
 - org.gradle.parallel=true
 - org.gradle.max=4
 :child1
 - build.gradle
 :child2
 - build.gradle
 :child3
 - build.gradle

How i can confirm my tasks are running in parallel? Kindly share your ideas/thoughts.

Tasks are running but i am not sure these are running in parallel or not.

Comment: Can someone provide help here?